# $ab(a+b) + bc(b+c) + ac(a+c) \geq \frac{2}{3}(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2})+ 4abc$ for $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=3$ and $a,b,c>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

> Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be positive real numbers with $\displaystyle \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=3$. Prove that:
>   $$
>   ab(a+b) + bc(b+c) + ac(a+c) \geq \frac{2}{3}(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2})+ 4abc.
> $$

Let us consider the following proofs. 
$$
  a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2} \geq ab+bc+ca
$$

By the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean Inequality we have 
$$
a^{2}+b^{2} \geq 2ab,\ \  b^{2}+c^{2} \geq 2bc,\ \ c^{2}+a^{2} \geq 2ca \tag{1}
$$
If we add together all the inequalities $(1)$, we obtain
$$
  2a^{2}+2b^{2}+2c^{2} \geq 2ab+2bc+2ca
$$

By dividing both side by $2$, the result follows.

Now let us consider,
 $$
  ab(a+b) + bc(b+c) + ac(a+c) \geq 6abc \tag{2}
$$

I already have proved $(2)$

Then, 
We are given, 
$$
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=3 \implies bc+ac+ab=3abc \tag{3}
$$
Notice that we have 
$$
a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2} \geq bc+ac+ab=3abc 
$$
So, 
$$
a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2} \geq 3abc \tag{4}
$$
Let us multiply both side of $(4)$ by $\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}$, yield
$$
\frac{2}{3}(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}) \geq 2abc 
$$

Here where I stopped. Would someone help me out ! Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, I am sure.Thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We note that
\begin{align*}
ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ac(a+c) &= a^2b+ab^2+b^2c+bc^2+a^2c+ac^2\\
&=\frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{b^2}{\frac{1}{a}} + \frac{b^2}{\frac{1}{c}}+
\frac{c^2}{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{c}}+\frac{c^2}{\frac{1}{a}}\\
&\ge \frac{4(a+b+c)^2}{2(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})} \qquad \mbox{(by the Schwarz inequality)}\\
&=\frac{2}{3}(a+b+c)^2\\
&=\frac{2}{3}(a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ac)\\
&=\frac{2}{3}(a^2+b^2+c^2) + \frac{4}{3}(ab+bc+ca)\\
&=\frac{2}{3}(a^2+b^2+c^2) + 4abc.
\end{align*}
Here, we employed the Schwarz inequality of the from
\begin{align*}
&\ (a+b+b+c+a+c)^2 \\
=&\ \left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{b}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{b}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}\right)^2\\
\le&\ \left(\frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{b^2}{\frac{1}{a}} + \frac{b^2}{\frac{1}{c}}+
\frac{c^2}{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{c}}+\frac{c^2}{\frac{1}{a}}\right)\left(2\big(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \big)\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Which mean have you used to come up with that $$\frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{b^2}{\frac{1}{a}} + \frac{b^2}{\frac{1}{c}}+
\frac{c^2}{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{c}}+\frac{c^2}{\frac{1}{a}}
\ge \frac{4(a+b+c)^2}{2(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})}$$

Comment: @ADAM: see updates above.

Comment: I would assume that inequality is right. $$
\left(\frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{b^2}{\frac{1}{a}} + \frac{b^2}{\frac{1}{c}}+
\frac{c^2}{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{c}}+\frac{c^2}{\frac{1}{a}}\right)\left(2\big(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \big)\right) \geq  4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+8(ab+ac+bc)
$$  so, you are done? they only thing left is $$ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ac(a+c) = a^2b+ab^2+b^2c+bc^2+a^2c+ac^2
=\frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{b^2}{\frac{1}{a}} + \frac{b^2}{\frac{1}{c}}+
\frac{c^2}{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{c}}+\frac{c^2}{\frac{1}{a}}$$ Is that right?

Comment: Would you please past the link of Schwarz inequality form  that you have used in your proof ! Thank you !

Comment: The general Schwarz inequality has the form $|\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i |\le (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)^{1/2}(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2)^{1/2}$. I think it is already there.

Comment: The identity $$ ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ac(a+c) = a^2b+ab^2+b^2c+bc^2+a^2c+ac^2
=\frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{b^2}{\frac{1}{a}} + \frac{b^2}{\frac{1}{c}}+
\frac{c^2}{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{c}}+\frac{c^2}{\frac{1}{a}}$$ in your comment is already there.

Comment: Did you FOIL this 



$$(\frac{a}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{b}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{b}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}})^2$$
To come up with this : 
$$(\frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{b^2}{\frac{1}{a}} + \frac{b^2}{\frac{1}{c}}+
\frac{c^2}{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{a^2}{\frac{1}{c}}+\frac{c^2}{\frac{1}{a}})(2\big(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \big)$$

Comment: @ADAM: yes, that is the Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @ADAM: Thanks for the bounty.

Comment: No problem at all! Though, it took a while to understand that you have applied Titu's Lemma which a consequence of C-S inequity.

Comment: @ADAM: I tried to avoid saying Titu's lemma, while prove it directly using the C-S inequality.

Answer (score 4):

We need to prove that
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\geq\frac{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}+4abc$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\geq\frac{2abc(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{ab+ac+bc}+4abc$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}ab\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\geq2abc(a^2+b^2+c^2)+4abc(ab+ac+bc)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^2+a^3c^2+2a^3bc+2a^2b^2c)\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}
(2a^3bc+4a^2b^2c)$$
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3b^2+a^3c^2-2a^2b^2c)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}c^2(a+b)(a-b)^2\geq0$$
Done!

Comment: If I conider the first one , which is $$ (a^2b+a^2c)+(b^2c+b^2a)+(c^2a+c^2b)$$. Would you explain how it this help me out ?

Comment: would you please give me any other hint! Thank you

Comment: @ADAM  I don't understand your question. It's just full expanding.

Comment: if I expand your work on the LHS it will come back as the original problem expat is different ordering. On the RHS you have replaced the 3 with $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=3$$

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)=(a^2b+a^2c)+(b^2c+b^2a)+(c^2a+c^2b)$$

Comment: @ADAM I used a full expanding: $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\geq\frac{2abc(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{ab+ac+bc}+4abc$ or $(ab+ac+bc)\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\geq2abc(a^2+b^2+c^2)+4abc(ab+ac+bc)$...

Comment: When I expand everything everything and drop of the smilier term in both sides I would have it likes this $$ a^{3}(b^2+c^2)+b^3(a^2+c^2)c^3(a^2+b^2) \geq 2a^2b^2c+2ab^2c^2+2a^2c^2b$$

Comment: @ADAM Id est, we need to prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3c^2+b^3c^2-c^2a^2b-c^2b^2a)\geq0$ or $\sum\limits_{cyc}c^2(a+b)(a-b)^2\geq0$

Comment: @ Michael You are answering my answer by another question! Thank you though !

Comment: @ADAM I tried to explain more.

Comment: Let me consider this one  $$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\geq\frac{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}+4abc$$, which is exactly same as the problem that I have posted but rewritten in different way. you have not proved it !!

Comment: @ADAM for the proof of $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\geq\frac{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}+4abc$ it's enough to prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\geq\frac{2abc(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{ab+ac+bc}+4abc$ and so on ...  it's enough to prove that  $\sum\limits_{cyc}c^2(a+b)(a-b)^2\geq0$, which is obvious. Thus, we are done.

Comment: Would you show me which methods have you follow to conclude that inequality holds  $$ (a^2b+a^2c)+(b^2c+b^2a)+(c^2a+c^2b) \geq \frac{2abc(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{ab+ac+bc}+4abc$$. Thank yu !

Comment: Because $\sum\limits_{cyc}ab\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\geq2abc(a^2+b^2+c^2)+4abc(ab+ac+bc)$, which is $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3b^2+a^3c^2+2a^3bc+2a^2b^2c)\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}
(2a^3bc+4a^2b^2c)$, id est, $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3b^2+a^3c^2-2a^2b^2c)\geq0$.